# Culture changes in Week Days

Tags: c#

I have a string "Saturday", i want to change this to some other language culture for example Ploish(Poland). How to change in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code example will change culture info to italian:

```
CultureInfo itCI = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = itCI;
```

Then, to get the right day of week (of today), you can do:

```
DayOfWeek giornoSet = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
string giornoSetS =CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(giornoSet);
```

Here's how to get a DayOfWeek from a string:

```
DayOfWeek wednesday = 
  (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), "Wednesday");
```

Comment: This will not help change the string "Saturday" to the equivalent in a different culture.

Comment: This still doesn't take into account the starting string "Saturday". You really need a line of code of `string dayname = "Saturday";` or similar to be properly using the input the question has.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture()` to create an instance of the `CultureInfo` you want, then use `DateTimeFormat.GetDayName()` to get the name of the specific day you want.

```
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pl-PL").DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DayOfWeek.Saturday)
```

To get the `DayOfWeek` for your original string, you can use `Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>("Saturday")`:

```
DayOfWeek day;

if (Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>("Saturday", out day))
{
    var dayInPolish = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pl-PL").DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(day);
}
```

Note that `Enum.TryParse` will only work if the input value is in English. You can use `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.DayNames` to find the day name in other languages.

[Here is a list of other culture codes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: It occurs to me that for this answer to be complete you need to clarify how to go from the string "Saturday" to `DayOfWeek.Saturday`

Comment: Edited. Missed that part :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pl-PL"))
```

**[EDIT]**

You may use this function:

```
private static string TranslateDay(string dayInStringFormat, string culture)
{
    try
    {
        return CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture).DateTimeFormat
            .GetDayName((DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), dayInStringFormat));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want the day today in a specific culture. He wants the string "Saturday".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTimeFormat.GetDayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getdayname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var culturePoland = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pl-PL");
DayOfWeek dow;
if (Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>("Saturday", out dow))
{
    string day = culturePoland.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(dow);
    Console.Write(day); // sobota
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/VZAx8o)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
var inputDay = "Saturday";
var SourceCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-gb");
var DestinationCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pl-pl");
var dayInt = Array.IndexOf(SourceCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames, inputDay);
Console.WriteLine(DestinationCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName((DayOfWeek)dayInt));
```

Please note that as written it is case sensitive on the day of the week and will throw an error if the day of the week is not found so some checks will need to be added.

Of note is that this specifies a source culture so if you had the name in french you could use this by just changing the source culture.